# How do I center an anchor element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I just want to have my anchor in the middle of the screen horizontally, how might I do this?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
```

Comment: I know it's old question but none of these alone really worked for me in Chrome. What did the job was 'text-align:center & display-block'. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Add the `text-align` CSS property to its *parent* style attribute

Eg:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>​
```

Or using a class (recommended)

```
<div class="my-class">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>​
```

```
.my-class {
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

See below working example:

```css
.my-class {
  text-align: center;
  background:green;
  width:400px;
  padding:15px; 
}
.my-class a{text-decoration:none; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<!--EXAMPLE-ONE-->
<div style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px #000; padding:15px;">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>​

<!--EXAMPLE-TWO-->
<div class="my-class">
  <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>​
```

---

***Q:** Why doesn't the `text-align` style get applied to the `a` element instead of the `div`?*

**A:** The `text-align` style describes how `inline` content is aligned within a `block` element. In this case, the `div` is a block element and it's inline content is the `a`. To further explore this consider how little sense it would make to apply the `text-align` style to the `a` element when it is accompanied by more text

```
<div>
  Plain text is inline content. 
  <a href="http://www.example.com" style="text-align: center">example</a> 
  <span>Spans are also inline content</span>
</div>
```

Even though there are line breaks here all the contents of `div` are inline content and therefore will produce something like:

> Plain text is inline content. [example](http://www.example.com) Spans are also inline content

It doesn't make much sense as to how "example" in this case would be displayed if the `text-align` property were to be applied.

Comment: Thanks for showing both ways. I need this for a very restricted proprietary application that has limited html box functionality where I can't reference CSS :( so have to use the not recommended method

Comment: The text-align CSS property describes how inline content is aligned inside a block element. In this case the `div` is the block element and `a` is inline content.

Comment: adding "display: inline-block;" to the css above should help if you don't see any changes

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to just change the display attribute without good reason.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer is valid change from `.my-class { ... }` to `div, a {...}` with the same body content?

Comment: Semantically those are not the same at all. `div, a { ... }` will apply the style rules to _all_ div and anchor elements in your code regardless of structure.

Answer (score 20):

write like this:

```
<div class="parent">
 <a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Two options, that have different uses:

HTML:

```
<a class="example" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
```

CSS:

```
.example { text-align: center; }
```

Or:

```
.example { display:block; width:100px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: What are the different uses?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
margin: 0 auto;
display: table
```

Comment: In many cases, that's the best answer as there is no additional markup needed. (like a parent `div`)

Comment: It helped me. I don't want to have a container

Answer (score 5):

try to wrap a `div` around and add these styles to the `div`:

```
 width: 100%; 
 text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<span style="text-align:center; display:block;">
<a href="http://news.awaissoft.com">Awaissoft</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default an anchor is rendered inline, so set `text-align: center;` on its nearest ancestor that renders as a block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that with inline elements like anchor, span. But to make it work you have to set the display to block.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" style="text-align:center;display:block;">example</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

```
<!-- Probably the most common: -->
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="...">Link</a></div>

<!-- Getting crafty... -->
<a href="..." style="display: block; text-align: center;">Link</a></div>
```

There are probably other ways too, but these three are probably the most common.

Answer (score 1):

css cannot be directly applied for the alignment of the anchor tag.
The css (text-align:center;) should be applied to the parent div/element for the alignment effect to take place on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
/**code starts here**/

a.class_name { display : block;text-align : center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`style="margin:0 auto; width:auto;"` Try that.

Answer (score 0):

It is very Simple Anchor(a) is a inline element, it means width of inline element is equal to how much text width is there that much.so if you want horizontal center so you need to convert inline to block element, then add text align center.

```
<a style="display:block;text-align:center" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

Just put it between center tags:

```
<center>><Your text here>></center>
```

Comment: In HTML5 `<center>` tag is not supported.

Comment: Do not follow this advice.

Comment: HTML encodes *semantic meaning*, not syntactic.  In otherwords, HTML describes the data and is not meant to describe the layout and presentation.  That's what CSS is for.  If you have to ask yourself about how your website will look like, it's almost certainly a CSS related task.  

Early in the days of HTML mistakes were made and style orientated tags were introduced.  As of HTML 5 most of them are deprecated (anyone remember <blink>?).  <center> itself was deprecated pretty early on in HTML 4 IIRC.