# align="centre" does not align the text to centre of block. Why?

Tags: html, tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>FirstProject</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 800px;border:solid red 15px;background-color: blue;color:white; margin:0 auto " >
        <h1 style="margin: 10px;padding:15px;background-color: black;color:blue;border:solid yellow 5px" align="center">MY FIRST WEBPAGE</h1>
        <p style="padding:10px;background-color: green;font-size: 40px;font-family: cursive;"align="center">Technology used is HTML and CSS.</p>
        <img src="image.png" alt="image.png"/>
        <a href="http://google.com" style="font-size: 60px;color:white" align="center">Google</a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why am I not getting Google in  at the centre of the block][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVgT3.png)

Comment: A possible duplicate.
Refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721831/how-do-i-center-an-anchor-tag-in-html][1]
It may answer your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721831/how-do-i-center-an-anchor-tag-in-html

Answer (score 1):

If you want everthing in you div to be centered you can use `text-align:center;` 
in your div.

But i wouldnt recommend this!

I would recommend that you reconstrukt the code with more divs

```
<body>
<div style="width: 800px;border:solid red 15px;background-color: blue;color:white; margin:0 auto " >
    <div>
          <h1 style="margin: 10px;padding:15px;background-color: black;color:blue;border:solid yellow 5px" align="center">MY FIRST WEBPAGE</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
           <p style="padding:10px;background-color: green;font-size: 40px;font-family: cursive;"align="center">Technology used is HTML and CSS.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
           <img src="image.png" alt="image.png"/>
           <a href="http://google.com" style="font-size: 60px;color:white" align="center">Google</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Dividing everything up will give you more controll over the elements, and you can center the divs content with `text-align:center;`. But for the question text-align:center in the outer div will solve your problems!